# pad database out with NULL criteria

Tags: sql, database

If I have the following sample table (order by ID)

```
ID    Date         Type
--    ----         ----
1     01/01/2000   A
2     22/04/1995   A
2     14/02/2001   B
```

Where you can immediate see that `ID=1` does not have a `Type=B`, but `ID=2` does. What I want to do, if fill in a line to show this:

```
ID    Date         Type
--    ----         ----
1     01/01/2000   A
1     NULL         B
2     22/04/1995   A
2     14/02/2001   B
```

where there could potentially be 100's of different types, (so may need to end up inserting 100's rows per person if they lack 100's Types!)

Is there a general solution to do this?

Could I possibly outer join the table on itself and do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `cross join` to generate all the rows and a `left join` to get the actual data values:

```
select i.id, s.date, t.type
from (select distinct id from sample) i cross join
     (select distinct type from sample) t left join
     sample s
     on s.id = i.id and
        s.type = t.type;
```